# Will BufferWithTime from Reactive Extensions invoke OnNext overlappingly?

Tags: .net, concurrency, system.reactive

I'm using BufferWithTime() from Rx to batch up processing of messages. If my OnNext method takes longer to complete than the time interval used, may I end up with two concurrent invocations of my OnNext methods?

Put another way, will the time interval specified in the BufferWithTime() call be evaluated in absolute terms, or will it act as an "asyncronous sleep" after my OnNext method returns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, calls to `OnNext` will be queued. The code below writes to the trace when the buffer time elapses, as well as the start/end of the OnNext call to the subscriber (in which it sleeps for 4 times the buffer time):

```
Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(50), Scheduler.TaskPool)
    .Take(50)
    .BufferWithTime(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100))
    .Do(_ => Trace.WriteLine("Buffer elapsed"))
    .ObserveOn(Scheduler.TaskPool)
    .Subscribe(_ =>
    {
        Trace.WriteLine("Begin OnNext");
        Thread.Sleep(200);
        Trace.WriteLine("End OnNext");
    });
```

The output is as follows. You can see that Begin/End OnNext never overlaps, even with `Buffer elapsed` occurs twice during an `OnNext` call:

> Buffer elapsed
>   Begin OnNext
>   Buffer elapsed
>   Buffer elapsed
>   End OnNext
>   Begin OnNext
>   Buffer elapsed
>   Buffer elapsed
>   Buffer elapsed
>   End OnNext
>   Begin OnNext
>   End OnNext
>   Begin OnNext
>   End OnNext
>   Begin OnNext
>   End OnNext
>   Begin OnNext
>   End OnNext